# What determines the X:\Sources content of Windows Setup Command?

Tags: windows, bootable-media

I wanted to modify the default bootable Windows 11 installation media by adding new file in the `sources` folder. I know how to do it (I have the "patched" ISO file already that boots correctly).

Problem arises that when I launch the Windows Setup Command (Shift+F10) I don't see my file in the `X:\Sources` directory - and really, I only managed to notice at that moment, that this catalog contains only selection of the items from `*.ISO\sources`.

1. What determines the *X:\Sources* content of Windows Setup Command? I've tried to run string search on content of the ISO file, but it yields no results, making me believe it could be some binary commands.
2. Maybe there is another way to include/run some files or at least execute batch file from Windows Setup Command? I'm interested in modifying only that in-memory system, **not** the one I'm installing. Which is hard to find on the internet, because all of my findings refer to customizing Windows instance instead the process of installation itself.

PS. I want to place specific registry entries before the installation process starts.

Comment: What commands did you run exactly to modify the ISO?  If you mount the ISO from within Windows, are the files in the directory you placed them in? I am asking these questions because I must assumed something isn't right otherwise you wouldn't be asking the question and understanding what you did is the only way to help you.  You should have course [edit] your question

Comment: @Ramhound I've extracted the contents using 7zip, added the file to `sources` directory. Then I've used the ImgBurn to create bootable ISO from the unpacked, patched original iso. As I've stated - ISO is booting and content of the ISO mounted in Windows is same as patched folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X:\Sources` is taken from `sources\boot.wim`. That's because `boot.wim` is an image of the environment you boot into to install Windows.

WIM files can be modified by [mounting them using `DISM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/mount-and-modify-a-windows-image-using-dism?view=windows-11).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you! Works flawlessly.